# React: Is useEffect() firing before the response arrives from the function I called?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

Does useEffect fire before the response for `data` arrives, hence the reason I get `undefined` immediately first before getting the proper data shortly after?

My logic is

1. `LoginScreen` and set `token` (jwt)
2. Define `isLoggedIn` state then conditionally render `HomeScreen`
3. On`HomeScreen` call `getUserDetails()` using the provided JWT

`HomeScreen`:

```
const {token, userInfo} = useContext(LoginContext)
const [stateUserInfo, setStateUserInfo] = userInfo
const [stateToken, setStateToken] = token

async function getUserDetails() {      
    const data = await axios.get(apiValidate+'&JWT='+stateToken)
    setStateUserInfo(data.data.data) //does this line run regardless if the response arrives or not?
}

useEffect(() => {
    getUserDetails()
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(stateUserInfo) //returns undefined 1st, then the proper object shortly after
},[stateUserInfo])
```

I 'fix' my code by doing:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(stateUserInfo) { 
        console.log(stateUserInfo) } 
},[stateUserInfo])
```

This works but I think it's ugly?

On a deeper question, I feel like I'm trying to do "synchronous" logic with async data! Is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe my logic is flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` will run on initial render as well. That means both of your effects will run the first time, but the second one will run when the `stateUserInfo` updates as well.

You can fix this by storing a boolean that validates if you're on the initial render or on subsequent ones. This way you can combine both effects into a single one.

Also, for the commented question in your code: YES, it will run regardless of the return of the server. You should add that request in a `try` `catch` in case it throws an error, and also check the response in case it is unexpected.

```js
const {token, userInfo} = useContext(LoginContext)
const [stateUserInfo, setStateUserInfo] = userInfo
const [stateToken, setStateToken] = token

// store a boolean to determine if you're on initial render
const afterUpdate = useRef(false)

async function getUserDetails() {      
    const data = await axios.get(apiValidate+'&JWT='+stateToken)
    setStateUserInfo(data.data.data) // this line WILL run regardless of the answer of the previous line, so you should validate the response first before assigning it.
}

useEffect(() => {
     if (afterUpdate.current) {
         console.log(stateUserInfo)
     } else {
        afterUpdate.current = true
        getUserDetails()
     }
},[stateUserInfo])
```